# Highlight rows where Text in one Column contains a Number Value from another Column

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have a sheet with data in 2 columns. Now I want to match/highlights all the rows that contain numbers in column A with column B.
But that column B  contains multiple values per cell (TEXT & NUMBERS).

[image]

just to verify all Column A are there or not in Column B. Please advise..

Comment: Please clarify:  Do you want to highlight rows where the Value in Column A (e.g. `A1`) is also in Column B (e.g. `B1`)?  Do you want to highlight rows where the Value in Column A (e.g. `A1`) exists *anywhere* in Column B (i.e. `B:B`)?  Or, do you want to highlight rows where the Value in Column B (e.g `B1`) contains *any* of the values in Column A (i.e. `A:A`)?  A manually filled-out example would help greatly, as would knowing **what have you already tried?**.

Comment: I want to highlight rows where the Value in Column A (e.g. A1) exists anywhere in Column B (i.e. B:B)?

Comment: [BigBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60974883/9290986) should do exactly that.  If you [edit] your question with that *much* clearer explanation, and explain why BigBen's solution doesn't work (as I suggested previously, screenshots of a "manually filled out" example is good, both to show us and to help you double-check the logic) then people can start voting to reopen your question too.

Answer (score 1):

In column C:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"*"&A1&"*")>0
```

[image]

Any FALSE result means that the number in column A is not present in column B.

Comment: i try this it shows wrong. Column A (5000 ENTRIES) IT WILL BE VERIFED BY TEXT & NUMBERS IN COLUMN B( 3000 ENTRIES)...

Comment: Please explain by editing your original question with how you tried it and how it is wrong.